Next.JS wait for rendered shadowRoot component to be rendered
I have a library component which create a shadowed DOM.
I want to change the color of one of its class.
This is the element it creates in the DOM:
<custom-lib ...>
   #shadow-root(open)
      <style>
         ...
      </style>
      <div class="change-me">
         ...
      </div>
</custom-lib>

What I do in my component at the moment is the following:
  ...
  const customLib = document.querySelector('custom-form');

  useEffect(() => {
    const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
    sheet.replaceSync(".change-me { color: red }");
    customLib?.shadowRoot?.adoptedStyleSheets.push(sheet);
  }, [customLib]);
  ...

The result is that or customLib or customLib.shadowRoot are null thus it does not apply.
I tried even with [customLib, customLib?.customLib] array dependency, yet same result...
How can I wait to get they rendered before applying css changes?
How can I wait to get they rendered before applying css changes?

React sucked for a very long time handling Web Components/DOM and Events. Not sure Next has a rendered callback in the 19 release? Like Lit, Stencil and the others all have some type of "parsedCallback". In native JavaScript code you have to add your own. Depending on your requirements can be as easy as one setTimeout; See my blogpost

Thank you, finally I solved in that way by setting a setTimeout. I had would like to avoid it but if there's no alternatives...

They've been going on for 8 years now if Native should have a parsedCallback. All tools use promises, raF, settimeout and the like. I you know what is actually happening setTimeout is enough.
